# Android I want to change TextView position while dragging

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to change textview location on dragging 
On touch event work for me well in creating shadow.

```
textview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    //ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText(textview.getText(),textview.getText());
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(textview);
                    textview.startDrag(null,shadowBuilder,textview,0);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But after drag event ends the shadow moves back to original state, But I need is to set textview to the shadow area

I don't want to replicate or create a copy of textview.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the code but got some position issue with textview and shadow

```
textview.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

             int x = (int)event.getX();
             int y = (int)event.getY();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
            textview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            return true;
        }
    });
```